# How to install gcc-4.4.6?

Tags: 11.10, gcc

My computer has Ubuntu 11.10 32-bit OS. I downloaded gcc4.4.6 core package (tar file), unzipped it and tried the following:

```
./configure   
sudo make install
```

which gave me the following error:

```
vidhya@vidhya-Reserved:~/Desktop/gcc-4.4.6$ sudo make install
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/vidhya/Desktop/gcc-4.4.6'
/bin/bash ./mkinstalldirs /usr/local /usr/local
/bin/bash: line 3: cd: host-i686-pc-linux-gnu/fixincludes: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [install-fixincludes] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vidhya/Desktop/gcc-4.4.6'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Could anyone please help me install any gcc 4.X version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install the **latest** version of [**gcc-4:4.6.1**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/gcc) through Official repositories just run

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.6 cpp-4.6 gcc-4.6 gcc-4.6-base
```

Or installing through [Ubuntu software center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/gcc/)

---

For the mentioned version **gcc 4.4.6** is already available through [**Oneric official repositories**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/i386/gcc-4.4/download).

Through terminal just run

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4 cpp-4.4 gcc-4.4 gcc-4.4-base
```

Or install it through [Ubuntu Software center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/gcc-4.4/). But the above **Latest version is always advisable**.

---

You don't have to use the **source** `.tar` package for installing , it is core library package and hence **recommended to install it via above official way.**

Comment: thank you! It worked. I want to install any gcc version from source package(tar file) because i want to edit the source code and recompile it. Is there any other way to modify the source code and recompile it? If so i will be happy to hear from u....

Comment: @vidhya- Glad that it helped .If the above solutions worked for for you , Do consider Marking it as [Answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) from the **Right tick mark** left to answer.You should probably try asking modification question as Different question  , explaining exactly what you want or need because it also helps other out here and also gets better answers.